# Что просят в задаче

Tags: c++, указатели, битовые-операции, приведение-типов

Я не понимаю, что хотят от меня в данной задаче? Сама задача:

Составить и проверить в действии функцию, составляющую 32 - разрядное
беззнаковое целое значение `uint32_t` из четырех байт данных.
Обращаться со значением нужно при этом как с простым массивом из 4
элементов типа `unsigned char`.

При этом :

- Использовать указатели;
- Применить операции приведения типов данных;
- Заполненное 32 - разрядное
  значение должно быть возвращено из функции.

Как я вижу решение этой задачи:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    uint32_t to_uint32_t(unsigned char _1, unsigned char _2, unsigned char _3, unsigned char _4)
    {
        uint32_t result; 
    
        unsigned char value [] { _1, _2, _3, _4 };
    
        result = 0xff & (static_cast<uint32_t>(_1));
    
        result << 8;
        result |= 0xff & (static_cast<uint32_t>(_2));
    
        result << 16;
        result |= 0xff & (static_cast<uint32_t>(_3));
    
        result << 24;
        result |= 0xff & (static_cast<uint32_t>(_4));
    
        return result;
    }
    
    int main(int args_count, char** args)
    {
        cout << to_uint32_t('9', '2', '3','4');
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: И в чём проблема с вашим решением?

Comment: @dIm0n я не могу понять, правильно ли я понял вообще задание, куда тут применить указатели?

Comment: ну если очень надо - используйте указатели для доступа к элементам массива из 4 байт. Можно массив и uint32 засунуть в один union - тогда вообще круто будет... сточки зрения учебного задания. Только есть сомнения, что выражение вида result << 8 что то поменяет без присваивания: result = result << 8;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, можно и проще:

```
uint32_t to_uint32_t(uint32_t _1, uint32_t _2,
                     uint32_t _3, uint32_t _4)
{
    return (_1 << 24) + (_2 << 16) + (_3 << 8) + _4;
}

int main(int args_count, char** args)
{
    cout << hex << to_uint32_t('9', '2', '3','4') << endl;
}
```

Т.е. возложить преобразование байта в число прямо при вызове функции.

Только вы точно имели в виду передачу именно символов? Т.е. первый байт у вас именно 0x39, ну и так далее? А не 9?

Ах, да, преобразование обязательно использовать... Ну, тогда

```
uint32_t to_uint32_t(uint8_t _1, uint8_t _2,
                     uint8_t _3, uint8_t _4)
{
    return
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(_1) << 24) |
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(_2) << 16) |
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(_3) << 8)  |
        static_cast<uint32_t>(_4);
}
```

Но куда воткнуть указатели?... Разве что так (ох, как сейчас меня побьют любители strict aliasing...) -

```
uint32_t to_uint32_t(uint8_t _1, uint8_t _2,
                     uint8_t _3, uint8_t _4)
{
    uint32_t r;
    uint8_t * s = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&r);
    *s++ = _4;
    *s++ = _3;
    *s++ = _2;
    *s++ = _1;
    return r;
}
```

Вопрос о порядке байтов в создаваемом числе оставляю открытым...

Comment: пожалуйста, не опирайтесь на мой код, так как я не знаю, правильно ли я понял задачу))), интересно, как бы вы решили эту задачу, не видя мой код), может вы совсем по другому подумали бы

Comment: Так вам дали пример с указателями. Суть указателей, что из байт можно составить int32 избегая сдвигов, как - показано на примере.

Comment: А что не так со strict aliasing? Каст к `char*` разрешён. Впрочем, ты зачем-то вместо `char` используешь `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да зашугали уже - что нельзя к чему-то одному обращаться через указатели на что-то другое... Откровенно - не чувствую я его совершенно (по-моему, если не извращаться специально - то никакой проблемы и не будет...). Ну, а `uint8_t` - так это уж точно беззнаковый байт...

Comment: @Duracell Так я и не опираюсь...

Comment: @Qwertiy, ууу, не получится из вас "любитель strict aliasing". Надо так: стандарт языка не гарантирует что тип `std::uint8_t` является псевдонимом для `char` или `unsigned char`. `std::uint8_t` может быть псевдонимом для какого-нибудь встроенного типа `__uint8`, который не является ни `char`, ни `unsigned char`. Следовательно, доступ к объекту типа `std::uint32_t` через указатель на объект типа `std::uint8_t` может быть неопределённым поведением. Следовательно, вызов функции `to_uint32_t` запросто может привести к удалению всех файлов на компьютере и взлому пентагона :))

Comment: @wololo Ну что поделать... весь наш менталитет протестует - жить по бездушному закону. Привыкли мы жить иначе - кто по совести, кто по понятиям :)  Вот и к языкам программирования примерно такое же отношение :)

Comment: @Harry, посылайте этих пуристов куда подальше. Проблемы strict aliasing реально существуют, но проявляются не в простых случаях, а когда оптимизатор, имея разные путии доступа к одной переменной, не в состоянии определить момент изменения ее значения. Возврат из функции таковым не является (это одна из точек синхронизации)

Comment: @avp, проблемы со strict aliasing-ом возникают в первую очередь из-за выравнивания. При обращении к неправильно выравненному объекту аппаратура может вызвать trap,  исключение или еще что-нибудь. Может не вызвать, но при обращение будет penalty (как в ARM). Так что рано еще посылать пуристов :)

Comment: @eanmos, как раз выравнивание (я уже не говорю о traps) **никак не связано** со strict aliasing. Проблема strict aliasing как раз в оторванности от памяти. Вместо последовательных операций с памятью (соответствующими логике программы) мы в результате оптимизации работаем с разными копиями памяти в разных регистрах (в рамках суперскалярности процессора это происходит даже параллельно).

Comment: @avp, почему не связано? Если мы кастим `U*` к `T*`, где `U` требует выравнивания на 4 байта, а `T` -- на 8 (а такой каст нарушает strict aliasing), то получаем доступ по невыровненному указателю, что и может привести к trap, исключению и т.д. Хотя с "в первую очередь" это я, конечно, погорячился.

Comment: @eanmos, [What is strict aliasing?
Strict aliasing **is an assumption**, made by the C (or C++) compiler, that dereferencing pointers to objects of different types **will never refer to the same memory location** (i.e. alias eachother.)](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) / А нарушение выравнивания это другой случай

Comment: @avp, нарушение выравнивания может произойти только при нарушении правил strict aliasing, так как все объекты с compatible types должны иметь одинаковые требования выравнивания.

Comment: @eanmos, imho это уже словоблудие (скорее расширенное толкование strict aliasing). Суть явлений разная, а вы играетесь формулировками из стандартов и некими логическими выводами из них

Comment: @avp, суть явлений действительно, разная. Но я имел в виду. что проблема с нарушением strict aliasing rules в том, что это может привести к нарушению требований выравнивания, а не то, что нарушение требований выравнивания = нарушение strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понял, от вас хотят ровно этого

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t
f (char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)
{
  uint32_t r;
  unsigned char *t = (__typeof__(t))&r;

  t[0] = c1; t[1] = c2; t[2] = c3; t[3] = c4;

  return r;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{

  uint32_t v = f('1', '2', '3', '4');

  printf("0x%02x\n", v);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем:

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ ttt.c -O3 && ./a.out
0x34333231
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ echo $?
0
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не это)), при разборе правильного ответа с преподавателем, оказывается, я был полностью на правильном пути, так же как и ответ @Harry (поэтому я его принял). p.s. не спрашивайте, что курят составители задач, ибо потом начинаешь гадать, что от тебя хотят на самом деле....)))

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>
using namespace std;

uint32_t fill_bytes(unsigned char array[4])
{
   uint32_t res;
   void* p = static_cast<void*>(&res);
   unsigned char* p_ar = static_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       p_ar[i] = array[i];
   return res;
}
  
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
   uint32_t v =1;
   unsigned char ar[4] = {1,2,3,4};
   cout << v << endl;
   v = fill_bytes(ar);
   cout << v << endl;
   uint32_t mask = 0xFF;
   for(int i = 0; i < 32; i += 8)
      cout << ((v& (mask << i)) >> i) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Теперь годится?